# Django. Automatically page refresh

Tags: javascript

For example, I show on my page the schedule of trains. How can I make automatically page refresh, when it will be next minute? Only using javascript?

Comment: you can use ajax requests to refresh a div, and fetch updates from the server periodically

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Answer (score 1):

Look into javascript `setTimeout`, and `location.reload()`

`location.reload()` refreshes the page, and `setTimeout` allows a function to be called in a certain amount of time.